# If $S$ is a martingale, then alle processes $((HS)_t)_t$ are martingales

Tags: martingales

I have just started with financial mathematics in discrete times, and while reading about martingales I came across this statement without proof, which I am not sure how I would prove. I would appreciate any help!

Statement: If $S$ is a martingale, then all processes $((HS)_t)_t$ are martingales, in particular $E[(HS)_T]=0$

Comment: What is $H$ here?

Comment: @user6247850 a strategy, $(HS)_t$ would be a stochastic integral